# Real integral giving complex result

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

I'm trying to calculate the following indefinite integral:

$$
\int \log \left(\left(\frac{\lambda ^2}{a \lambda ^2+b}+\text{$\Delta $0}\right)^2\right) \, d\lambda
$$

which is producing the following result:

$$
\lambda  \log \left(\left(\frac{\lambda ^2}{a \lambda ^2+b}+\text{$\Delta $0}\right)^2\right)+\frac{4 \sqrt{b} \sqrt{\text{$\Delta $0}} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\lambda  \sqrt{a \text{$\Delta $0}+1}}{\sqrt{b} \sqrt{\text{$\Delta $0}}}\right)}{\sqrt{a \text{$\Delta $0}+1}}-\frac{4 \sqrt{b} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{a} \lambda }{\sqrt{b}}\right)}{\sqrt{a}}
$$

This results seems correct except that for some values of `a`, `b`, and $\Delta_0$, it is returning a complex number. For example:

```
Integrate[Log[(Δ0 + λ^2/(a λ^2 + b))^2], λ] 
  /. a -> 0.87 /. b -> 2000 /. Δ0 -> -1.1 /. λ -> 300
```

gives the result

> ```
> -1706.06 - 1421.21 I
> ```

Numerically integrating the function it seems as if the real part of the expression is correct. For example:

```
NIntegrate[
  Log[(Δ0 + λ^2/(a λ^2 + b))^2] /. a -> 0.87 /. b -> 2000 /. Δ0 -> -1.1, 
  {λ, 0, 300}]
```

gives

> ```
> -1706.05
> ```

My question is twofold:

1. Why is Mathematica returning an expression for this integral which can evaluate to a complex number?
2. Is it possible to obtain an expression which always evaluates to a real number, ideally one which contains no complex numbers as intermediate results in the expression?

Comment: A numerical value for an integral only really makes sense if you specify limits.  I suggest you determine suitable limits, and you may then find that you get a purely real answer.

Comment: @mikado I'm evaluating the expression from $\lambda$ = 0 to $\lambda$ = 300.

Comment: @user545424 Then use `Integrate[..., {λ, 0, 300}]` instead of `Integrate[..., λ]`.

Comment: Isn't the argument for the log negative for  lambda = 0?

Comment: @mikado the argument to the log function is squared.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, I can certainly change the indefinite integral to a definite integral. Why does that output anything different than just evaluating the indefinite integral at the bounds?

Comment: In evaluating an indefinite integral, Mathematica makes certain assumptions about the symbolic parameters.  If you then substitute values that don't satisfy these assumptions, it can give you the wrong answer.

Comment: Are these assumptions listed anywhere? I thought that Mathematica would output a ConditionalExpression with all of it's assumptions if the result wasn't valid for all values of the symbolic parameters.

Comment: Just found this post http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/01/19/mathematica-and-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus/ which seems to explain things pretty well. Thanks!

Comment: @MarcoB, Indeed that question and answer seem to solve my problem, however I wonder if I should mark this as a duplicate if only because I was unable to find that result in the first place since my problem *seemed* to be related to a real integral giving a complex answer (there are other similar questions, but I don't think they have the same problem as I had here). Happy to mark as a duplicate if that's the best thing, but perhaps an answer on this question explaining the issue and pointing to that question would be better.

Comment: @user545424 Marking this question as a duplicate does exactly that, i.e. it provided a link to the previous question and the answers therein, so it is indeed the best way to go.